# Trying to print out Latvian characters into Zebra ZT230

Tags: fonts, special-characters, zpl

I try to print out the Latvian characters (eg. Ā,Ē,Ī,Ū and Č,Š,Ž and Ģ,Ķ,Ļ,Ņ) with Swiss721 font, but almost with every letter nothing comes out.

These character I would expect to be printed out:
Ā,Č,Ē,Ģ,Ī,Ķ,Ļ,Ņ,Š,Ū,Ž
with this code:
^FO10,80^A2,30,20^FH_^FD_c4_80 _c4_8c _c4_92 _c4_a2 _c4_aa _c4_b6 _c4_bb _c5_85 _c5_a0 _c5_aa _c5_bd ^FS

I need to send these characters as hex, because my Linux platform doesn't support these characters.

^XA
^CI28
^FO60,75
^ASN,36,20^FH^FDAlvaro Jes_c3_bas P_c3_a9rez Pe_c3_b1aranda_c4_80^FS
^XZ

eg. This example prints out 
Alvaro Jesús Pérez Peñaranda

Everything else correct but the last character _c4_80 (Ā) is missing

How do I manage to print out these Latvian characters? Should I link another font type with Swiss721 or what should I do??

Answer (score 0):

Try using their Swis721 Font.

https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/unicode-printing-using-the-free-swiss-721-font-for-zebra-zpl-printers.html

Will need to add the font command. Like this when assigned to Z.

```
^AZN,36,15
```

I've verified that font contains 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH MACRON'

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer! 
I finally got this done. I found the right syntax, thanks to your (EdHayes3) help. I tried this also before, but i'm sure that my code syntax was not correct. Now I got this working!!!

^XA
^LH100,150
^CWT,E:TT0003M_.FNT
^CFT,30,30
^CI28
^FO10,80^A2,30,20^FH_^FD_c4_80 _c4_8c _c4_92 _c4_a2 _c4_aa _c4_b6 _c4_bb _c5_85 _c5_a0 _c5_aa _c5_bd ^FS  ^XZ

Wbr,
Markku Hirvonen